# pgadmin 4 connection failed Issue. Connection to server at "localhost (::1), port 5432 failed

Tags: python, postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-9.3, pgadmin-4

I am having this issue very frequent now. The temp fix is to delete everything and install again. But as soon as i close pgadmin this issue comes again. Anyone knows a solution to this in macos?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your server may not be running locally.
Run your server from sql shell and ensure that it’s running on port 5432. Then pgAdmin should connect it.